# Getting key value pairs with linux server

Tags: json, regex, linux, awk, grep

I am looking to get a key pair from json that is not formatted correctly, so I cannot use jq or other ways of grabbing the JSON key value pairs.  Also, the data does not print in a specific order so I can't get it by specific columns or field numbers.

What is the best way to do this?  I'm having issues building a regular expression or using cut to get this working.

```
 root# python3 getprice.py 
{'bid': '11546.94', 'ask': '11551.96', 'volume': {'USD': '51726566.064352112368', 'TLC': '4388.676466043', 'timestamp': 1561785300000}, 'last': '11551.96'}
root# python3 getprice.py
{'last': '11551.96', 'bid': '11546.94', 'ask': '11551.96', 'volume': {'timestamp': 1561785300000, 'USD': '51726566.064352112368', 'TLC': '4388.676466043'}}
root# python3 getprice.py
{'bid': '11547.44', 'ask': '11551.96', 'volume': {'TLC': '4388.676466043', 'timestamp': 1561785300000, 'USD': '51726566.064352112368'}, 'last': '11551.96'}
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `I am looking to get a key pair` - which key pair? What do you want to do with them after you "get" them? Is the formatted block of 6 lines of text you posted your sample input file or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like JSON but with quotes. If your file is like this:

```
$ cat file.txt
{'bid': '11546.94', 'ask': '11551.96', 'volume': {'USD': '51726566.064352112368', 'TLC': '4388.676466043', 'timestamp': 1561785300000}, 'last': '11551.96'}
```

then you can:

```
$ cat file.txt | tr "'" '"' | jq '.'
{
  "bid": "11546.94",
  "ask": "11551.96",
  "volume": {
    "USD": "51726566.064352112368",
    "TLC": "4388.676466043",
    "timestamp": 1561785300000
  },
  "last": "11551.96"
}
```

or just to get one value out like the `ask` value:

```
$ cat file.txt | tr "'" '"' | jq '.ask'
"11551.96"
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks


`$ echo $var | tr "'" '"' | jq '.'
{
  "ask": "11940.82",
  "last": "11940.82",
  "bid": "11933.96",
  "volume": {
    "timestamp": 1561824300000,
    "USD": "38192560.400293180286",
    "TLC": "3210.2696148893"
  }
}
$ echo $var | tr "'" '"' | jq '.ask'
"11940.82"
$ echo $var | tr "'" '"' | jq '.bid'
"11933.96"
$ echo $var | tr "'" '"' | jq '.last'
"11940.82"`

Answer (score 0):

Other than writing your own custom parser the simplest way to parse that data is probably `eval` it in node.js (an old technique to parse JSON before `JSON.parse()`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env node
// A simple script to parse javascript objects from stdin (not just JSON)

// Pass the key you want to extract as argument:
let key = process.argv[2];

let rawData = '';

process.stdin.on('data', x => rawData += x.toString());
process.stdin.on('end',() => {
    eval('var obj = ' + rawData);   // CAREFUL - EVAL IS EVIL!!!
    console.log(eval 'obj.' + key); // ALSO EVIL!
});
```

Save the above script as `'jsonparse'` and make it executable. Then you can use it like:

```
python3 getprice.py | jsonparse bid
python3 getprice.py | jsonparse volume.USD
```

Comment: This sounds great I'm having all types of issues making node an executable or running this as a  node command


`# python3 getprice.py | ./jsonparse bid
-bash: ./jsonparse: No such file or directory
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
root@`   

`# python3 getprice.py | jsonparse bid
jsonparse: command not found
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: Just chmod it to make it executable: `chmod +x jsonparse`